# why javascript distinguish the assignment with or without declaration when delete?

Tags: javascript

Execute the code below in the global context:

```
var x = 1;
y = 1
delete x //false
delete y //true
```

Both `x` and `y` is property of global object. Why javascript have to distinguish them in some extent?

---

It's easy to follow the routine accoring to ES5 standard [the `delete` operator](http://es5.github.io/#x11.4.1) and the [the object internal method`[[delete]]`](http://es5.github.io/#x8.12.7).

The more clear question expressed is that **why** the different `[[configurable]]` attribute they adopt ?

Comment: @FelixKling Hi,see you again! But I'm not understand why they have the different `[[configurable]]` attribute. You know I read the standard but didn't find any proof for that. Such decision is driven by?

Comment: Well I cannot tell you that, I didn't make that decision :) Maybe you should contact someone working on the ECMAScript standard.

Answer (score 5):

Look at the second answer in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/difference-between-using-var-and-not-using-var-in-javascript) by [kangax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/130652/kangax).

> var x = 1 declares variable x in current scope (aka execution
>   context). If declaration appears in a function - local variable is
>   declared; if it's in global scope - global variable is declared.
>
> x = 1, on the other hand, is merely a property assignment. It first
>   tries to resolve x against scope chain. If it finds it anywhere in
>   that scope chain, it performs assignment; if it doesn't find x, only
>   then it creates x property on a global object (which is a top level
>   object in a scope chain).
>
> Now, notice that it doesn't declare global variable, it creates a
>   global property.
>
> The difference between two is subtle and might be confusing unless you
>   understand that variable declarations also create properties (only on
>   a Variable Object) and that every property in Javascript (well,
>   ECMAScript) have certain flags that describe their properties -
>   ReadOnly, DontEnum and DontDelete.
>
> Since variable declaration creates property with DontDelete flag, the
>   difference between var x = 1 and x = 1 (when executed in global scope)
>   is that former one - variable declaration - creates DontDelete'able
>   property, and latter one doesn't. As a consequence, property created
>   via this implicit assignment can then be deleted from the global
>   object, and former one - the one created via variable declaration -
>   can not be.

Comment: This is also sort of documented here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete